# Existential import of particular proposition

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I saw that in categorical logic the proposition, some $A$ is $B$ is considered to have existential import meaning we assume there exists a particular in class $A$ but the proposition, "All $A$ is $B$ mean that if $A$ is empty" the proposition is true, why is that saying "some unicorns are pink" is a false statement while saying "All unicorns are pink" is a true statement?

Answer (score 1):

The issue of so-called existential import of [categorical proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition) has a long history.

In modern logic "Some A is B" is symbolized with $\exists x (Ax \land Bx)$ and thus it is true only when there are $A$s and $B$s.

The universal, instead, is symbolized with $\forall x (Ax \to Bx)$ which is true also when there are no $A$s.

> [Why] saying "All unicorns are pink" is a true statement?

Because the [conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional#Truth_table) $Ax \to Bx$ is true when the *antecedent* $Ax$ is False.

According to [Arsitotle's Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#PreStrAss) and the so-called [Square of Opposition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/square/), we have that the universal imples the corresponding particular, but in modern logic the imference:

> $\forall x (Ax \to Bx)$, therefore $\exists x (Ax \land Bx)$

is not valid, exactly due to the counter-examples like yours.

For some references, see:

- Joseph Wu, [The problem of existential import (1969)](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093893792), and:
- John Corcoran & Hassan Masoud, [Existential Import Today: New Metatheorems; Historical, Philosophical, and Pedagogical Misconceptions (2015)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273836464_Existential_Import_Today_New_Metatheorems_Historical_Philosophical_and_Pedagogical_Misconceptions).